# Array lost between one proceedure and another - how to pass array?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi there Im not hot on OOP, and searching here couldnt find the answer. Ive one proceedure call it p1.php where **$user** array should be available in p2.php but its not. What happens is $user is set when in p1.php, but empty on entry to p2.php, but reinstances on return to p1.php Can anyone suggest why? I know I can pass $user via the function call but thats not the object of the exercise ;-)

```
    //p1.php    
if ($user->user_data['startemailmode'] == 'yes')
{                                        $send_email->confirmation($auctionData->auction_id, $auctionData->title, $auctionData->atype, $auctionData->pict_url, $auctionData->minimum_bid, $auctionData->reserve_price, $auctionData->buy_now_price, $auctionData->ends);}

 //p2.php
   public function confirmation($auction_id, $title, $atype, $pict_url, $minimum_bid, $reserve_price, $buy_now_price, $a_ends)
{   
       if (!isset($user->user_data['name'])) return null;   
        $this->emailer->assign_vars(array(.....
```

Comment: Show us more code. Do you put `$user` in `p1.php` into session (or somewhere else) and pick it back up in `p2.php` from there? Or where does `$user` come from? We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I couldnt find the answer I was looking for so I used a compromise by using a global variable (global $user) which unlike what Im used to in C this variable once declared, makes the variable from another procedure available available to the local procedure:

```
        public function confirmation($auction_id, $title, $atype, $pict_url, $minimum_bid, $reserve_price, $buy_now_price, $a_ends)
{   
        global $user;
        if (!isset($user->user_data['name'])) return null;
```

Thanks to Mike below for the correct answer.

Comment: allow me to introduce you to PHP sessions. Which is almost certainly what you want to be using. You start a session, then use $_SESSION as your data transport between different files and even different requests over time.